# how to check mariaDB ODBC driver version From java code

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I want to check `mariaDB ODBC` driver version in my JAVA application.
*Is is possible or How can I do it?*
Could anyone help , I searched a lot but didn't get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` to determine version. For example -

```
Class.forName("com.odbc.Driver");   
Connection con =
DriverManager.getConnection("NAME"); // Advanced Server Database Connection 
DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();  

System.out.println("DatabaseMajorVersion: " + metadata.getDatabaseMajorVersion() ); 
System.out.println("DatabaseMinorVersion: " + metadata.getDatabaseMinorVersion() );
```

This is just a pseudo code. Hope this helps.